# How to get an EC2 Windows machine's instance-id into a batch variable

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, batch-file

I have a batch file that I'd like to run on startup of an EC2 Windows AMI.  The program I'd like to run from that batch file takes the instance-id of the EC2 machine as a parameter.  What is the simplest way to get that Instance ID passed as an argument to that program?

From [Amazon's Documentation on the subject](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/2008-08-08/DeveloperGuide/index.html?AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html), I see that you're supposed to issue a WGET to a specified URL and parse the response.  So an alternate way of phrasing this question might be "How do I pass the contents of a HTTP request to a program as an argument in a Windows batch file"

In pseudocode, this is what I'd like to do:

```
set ID = GET http://169.254.169.254/2008-08-08/meta-data/instance-id
myprogram.exe /instanceID=%ID%
```

Any suggestions on how I might proceed?

Answer (score 8):

PowerShell 3.0 and [Invoke-WebRequest](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx):

```
PS> $instanceId = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```

Or if you need to survive in batch, us a win32 binary of [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html).

Or based on your use-case, you could use CloudFormation to get the Instance-Id during the API call and pass it to cf-init for a [bootstrap action](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-windows-stacks-bootstrapping.html) for your application deployment.

Comment: This returns a webresponse - in order to get the actual id - you might want to use: `$instanceId = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id).Content`

Answer (score 3):

Alternative: maybe you could do this using **PowerShell** on Amazon's EC2. Here are some links to start:

- [EC2Dream - Scripting with PowerShell](http://www.ec2dream.com/2009/05/scripting-with-powershell.html)
- [PowerShell and Amazon Web Service](http://www.kombitz.com/2006/07/19/powershell-and-amazon-web-service/)

Answer (score 2):

Powershell would be the easiest way to do this:

$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient 
$myip = $webclient.DownloadString("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4") 
myprogram.exe /instanceID=$myip

Answer (score 2):

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;
$instanceIdResult = $wc.DownloadString("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id")
Write-Host $instanceIdResult
```

Comment: How is this any different from the other answer using a WebClient and DownloadString??

Answer (score 2):

So I found another way of doing this:

```
$instanceId = Get-EC2InstanceMetadata -Path '/instance-id'
```

It seems a lot cleaner and result contains just what you expect "Instance ID"

Answer (score 0):

`wget` doesn't have an option to output the contents of the downloaded file to screen (or at least the version I have here doesn't), so you have to use a temporary file anyway. What you can do then is the following:

```
wget -O "instance-id" "http://169.254.169.254/2008-08-08/meta-data/instance-id"
set /p ID=< instance-id
```

`set /p` usually prompts for something and we just redirect the file's contents here. This assumes that the instance ID is the only thing that's in that file. You can have a little more fun with parsing text when using `for /f` but for a simple "put the first line of that file into a variable" `set /p` suffices.

Comment: Does wget -O - http://... not output the file to standard out?

Comment: Ah, drat. Wasn't written into `wget --help` but it works, yes. Sorry.